# SSRS 2nd page of the report is broken

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

This is the first page. There is a line above the table.

[image]

Here is the second page, the line dis appear and the charts moved to the top.

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a pretty easy solution, actually.  I'm going to assume that the `Umsatz` and the date are contained in the header to repeat on each page.  the simplest solution will be to remove the line object and simply apply a border on the lower edge of your header.  Simply click inside the blank area of the header, and use the top bar to select the border on the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, but the issue is still there. It did not solved it.